# having trouble sending discord "say" command message argument

Tags: javascript, discord.js, arguments, command

So, I'm coding a discord bot using discord.js and I'm making a "say" command. I watched a few tutorials which didn't work, asked a few friends, and I've got nothing. This is the file's code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'say',
    description: "Says message",

    async run (client, message, args) {


        if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.channel.send('You dont have the permissions to do this command!')
        if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.channel.send('Sorry, it seems I dont have the permissions to do that command.')


        if(!args[0]) return message.reply('please tell me what to say.');

        message.channel.send(`${args.join(" ")}`);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I could make this actually work? thanks!

Comment: Also, I'm not that good at JS yet in case any of you are wondering how I got this to not work.

Comment: Thanks, but what I'm having trouble with is saving the message the user sends and sending that message with the bot. Sorry for not being that specific. Ima fix that now.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Without providing the error, its hard to so what went wrong.

Comment: Can you show us the code that calls the command?

Comment: No errors showed up. It simply didn't respond. It responds with "Please tell me what to say" when I don't give it anything to say and just run the command, but when I DO give it something to say, it doesnt say anything.

Comment: Also, this is my command handler. Though I'm not sure thats what you meant.

`const commandFiles = readdirSync(join(__dirname, "commands")).filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));

for(const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(join(__dirname, "commands", `${file}`));
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but might be cuz of you didn't include arguments into your module.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'say',
    description: "Says message",

    args: true,
```

**args: true**

Comment: `args` is in the `run(...)` parameters

Comment: I know... But you have to set true in args. Have you even tried it?

Comment: No command handler, including the one officially presened by [Discord.JS](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/#individual-command-files), requires having a key of `args` being set to true. How would this affect the execution of the function.